# why doesn't 'do javascript' call in Applescript execute when the same code typed into browser does?

Tags: javascript, macos, dom, applescript

I'm trying to figure out why my Applescript does nothing when the same javascript code typed into a Safari location bar works.

Go to a search results page, such as: http://www.google.com/search?q=test .  For the correct behavior, type this into the location bar and hit enter:

```
javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('vspib')[0].click();
```

You'll see that it selects the magnifier for the first search result.

This is what I want to make happen via javascript.  So I typed up the following:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('vspib')[0].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

However, it does nothing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `do JavaScript` has to correctly address a tab in a Safari window.

The following script works for me, if the search results page is the current tab in the frontmost Safari window:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set theScript to "document.getElementsByClassName('vspib')[0].click();"
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Comment: thanks so much.  for some reason your code wasn't working every time for me, but this modification ended up doing the trick: execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('vspib')[0].click();"