# How can I execute JavaScript function in AppleScript?

Tags: javascript, applescript

I tried this apple script with Script Editor. 
But it doesn't take me to the page where it usually goes when it's clicked manually.
It seems doing nothing :(

```
do JavaScript "doCallerPage('FORM_PAGE', 'FR_AN', '/as/an/Check.do');return false;" in document 1
```

The Link in HTML source

```
<a id="LNK0001" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doCallerPage('FORM_PAGE', 'FR_AN', '/as/an/Check.do');return false;">Check Page</a>
```

JavaScript Function

```
function doCallerPage(formName, target, actionPath, _action, _t) {
        if (actionPath == "") {
            return false;
        }

        if (target && target != "_self") {
            checkSubWindow(target);
        }
        if (document.FORM_PAGE.ctrlflg.value == "") {
            if (_action) {
                document.FORM_PAGE._ACTION.value = _action;
            }
            else if (!_action) {
                document.FORM_PAGE._ACTION.value = "";
            }
        }
        if (_t) {
            document.FORM_PAGE._T.value = _t;
        }
        else {
            document.FORM_PAGE._T.value = "";
        }
        document.FORM_PAGE.action = actionPath;
        document.FORM_PAGE.target = target;
        document.FORM_PAGE.submit();
        document.FORM_PAGE._P.value = "";
        document.FORM_PAGE._T.value = "";
        document.FORM_PAGE._ACTION.value = "";
        document.FORM_PAGE.ctrlflg.value = "";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why doesn't 'do javascript' call in Applescript execute when the same code typed into browser does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561452/why-doesnt-do-javascript-call-in-applescript-execute-when-the-same-code-typed)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I tried that before post. But it didn't work in my case :(

Comment: The basic problem is that JavaScript functions only exist in the context of the page that defines them.  You can't just run a JavaScript function by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So there is no solution to jump to the page automatically when it's handled by javascript transition like this?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is a little different and it has to be javascript. Using jQuery on Chrome can be done like so:

`tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set jq to do shell script "curl https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    execute front window's active tab javascript jq
    execute front window's active tab javascript "jQuery('body').css({'color':'blue'});"
end tell`

Vanilla JS:

`tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    execute front window's active tab javascript "if (window.console) console.log( 'hi' );"
end tell`

You can be doing other things in other applications while this is happening the script will execute as long as the browser window is left as is until the script is complete.