# Why does my getElementById( ) result with "missing value" in Applescript?

Tags: javascript, applescript, getelementbyid

My goal is to determine whether or not an element is on a page and perform an action on that element, if it exists.

In this code, I'm only showing the second part of trying to perform an action on an element.

My code is:

```
tell application "Safari" 
    open location "http://www.apple.com" 
    tell front document 
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"gn-store\").click()" 
    end tell 
end tell
```

However, I always get a result of "missing value", from this code and similar things I've tried (including calling a function in Js, to return a value from getElementById( ).

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've been at it for hours. (and for the record, I am an applescript noob).

Comment: This will probably look terrible in mini-Markdown formatting, but tis work - checks for an element, then clicks if it exists:

tell application "Safari"
 
 open location "http://www.apple.com"
 delay 3
 tell front document
  set appearance to do JavaScript "document.contains(document.getElementById('gn-store'))"
 end tell
 
 if appearance is true then tell front document
  do JavaScript "document.getElementById('gn-store').childNodes[0].click()"
 end tell
 
end tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find Chrome reacts better to Javascript via AppleScript...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set its URL to "http://www.apple.com/"
        delay 3
        execute javascript "document.getElementById('gn-store').childNodes[0].click()"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: the "childNodes" part did the trick! 

I used my original code, added a 3 sec. delay after "open location", and after "do Javascript", I copy pasted your code code after "execute javascript" -- worked perfectly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, now there's the problem of determining whether or not the element is on the page...

Comment: document.contains(document.getElementById('gn-store'))

Comment: childNodes  Must remember that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to get the element before it exists (the page just started loading). Try this:

```
do JavaScript "window.onload=function(){document.getElementById(\"gn-store\").click()}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still results in "missing value"

    tell application "Safari"
 open location "http://www.apple.com"
 do JavaScript "window.onload=function(){document.getElementById(\"gn-store\").click()}"
  --> missing value
end tell
Result:
missing value

Comment: Found a possible duplicate, does it solve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561452/why-doesnt-do-javascript-call-in-applescript-execute-when-the-same-code-typed

Comment: No. I tried filling in my element, changing it from "ByClass" to "ById", and went back to "getElementById". I got nothing.

I also attempted that code, multiple times (in the address bar, and with the modification in the comments); I couldn't get it to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in Applescript to click this button. It involves GUI Scripting, which can be enabled by checking the 'Enable Access for Assistive Devices' checkbox in the Accessibility pane of System Preferences (as shown).
[image: How to enable GUI Scripting]

You can click 'Store' on the Apple site by using

```
tell application "Safari"
    open
    activate
    set frontmost to true
    open location "http://www.apple.com"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    delay 3
    tell UI element 2 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window "Apple" to perform action "AXPress"
end tell
```