# Applescript JavaScript "End of Line but found identifier" Error when controlling Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, applescript

The following is a part of my AppleScript script that should click an element in the current tab of Google Chrome with name 'connect'.

```
tell app "Google Chrome"
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('connect').click();" in current tab of first window
end
```

When is runs, it returns the following syntax error:

> Expected end of line but found identifier.

How would I get this to work?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561452/why-doesnt-do-javascript-call-in-applescript-execute-when-the-same-code-typed  There may be some similarity in the target syntax?

Comment: Yeah, tried that one. I wouldn't have posted the question if I had tried other answers and they worked.

Comment: Well.. Alright. Thanks.. I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it out.

Here's the code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementsByName('connect')[0].click()"
end tell
```